# How do you show that 2 lines $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are perpendicular(orthogonals) but using this result $ ||u+v||=||u-v||$

Tags: linear-algebra

My question has 2 parts, I m struggling with the second one.

Let's see the first:Prove that the vectors $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, if and only 
if $\| u + v \| = \| u - v \|$

<=

If $u,v$ are orthogonal vectors, then:(by Phythagoras'theorem)
$$\| u + v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$
$$\| u - v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|-v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2$$
now $\| u + v \|^2 = \| u - v \|^2$, but the norm is ever positive therefore:
$\| u + v \| = \| u - v \|$.

=> Now, if $\| u + v \| = \| u - v \|$ we have:

$\| u + v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 + 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$

$\| u - v \|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$

By the equality

$\|u\|^2 + 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 - 2u\cdot v + \|v\|^2$ if and only if

$2u\cdot v = -2u\cdot v \Leftrightarrow 4u\cdot v = 0 \Leftrightarrow u\cdot v = 0$

this is $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal
I understand this part. OK

Let's see the second part of the question.

Considering the previous result of the proof(orthogonal vectors)

Show that $L_{1}=(1,2,3)+t(1,-1,1)$

And $L_{2}=(0,3,2)+t(5,2-3)$ are perpendiculars.

I think that the main point here is to consider that $uv=0$ means orthogonal but I have no idea how to use this result to show the Lines $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are perpendiculars(orthogonals). Suggestions or hints will be welcome. Thanks

Comment: For the second part, why wouldn’t you simply compute the dot product of the two direction vectors directly?

Comment: Because the instruction says that I must use the result of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\|(1,-1,1)+(5,2,-3)\|=\sqrt{41}=\|(1,-1,1)-(5,2,-3)\|.$$

Comment: Should I consider both vectors equal to 0 to show that it is orthogonal?

Comment: @Malu: I gave you the complete answer.

Comment: So this is the intermediate step $||(x,y,z)||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. It looks so simple. Sometimes I stuck in the middle of simple things. Im overthinking 

Comment: @Malu: the hint was given in the question !

Comment: If the equality holds , it means that it is orthogonal. right?

Comment: @Malu yes, that's what you just proved. Once you prove something feel free to believe it.

Comment: Thank you guys.